# ORDER BY date sorts only using days and months mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's my sql query :

```
SELECT uid, title, startTime, endTime, cover FROM event ORDER BY startTime DESC
```

But this will bring me elements in this order :

```
 12/30/2013      00:00
 12/25/2013      00:00
 01/10/2014      00:00
```

Looks like it's sorting only using days and months.

Do you have any idea about this ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't store your dates as strings

Comment: Unix timestamps would also be a good option.

Comment: @JohnConde : Thank you, I have just arrived in this project so I didn't design the databse my self :D and yes you are right they are stored as Strings...

Comment: @ViniciusMonteiro they are stored as Varchar

Comment: As already answered, just convert to date. Don't forget to mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you really have stored them as string, [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) should be able to solve this.

```
SELECT uid, title, startTime, endTime, cover 
FROM event 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( startTime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) DESC
```

Comment: Shouldn't that format start with the year?  There is a chance he could still run into the same problem.

Comment: @Flosculus the format tells MySQL what the input format is, not what the output format should be

Comment: @LarsBeck yes, I will. I'm only waiting from stack to allow me to do it (you can accept an answer in x minutes) :D

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are being stored as a string or varchar, which means the standard formatting or `DATETIME` format is thrown completely out the window.

If you re-format the column to a `DATETIME`, you would get rows like this

```
2013-12-15 00:00:00
2013-12-30 00:00:00
2014-01-10 00:00:00
```

You can see that the most significant unit is the first in the string order, whereas the smallest unit is the last in the string, thus allowing for simple ordering.

Using @Lars suggestion to have the `STR_TO_DATE()` function with ordering, you should run the following query after creating a new column (let's call it `newStartTime`) of the structure `DATETIME`:

```
UPDATE event SET newStartTime = STR_TO_DATE( startTime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i' );
```

Then eventually throw out the `startTime` column **after you depreciate its usage in the application that you've taken over.** You should do this because string to `DATETIME` conversion is time-consuming and will result in long query execution times as you approach large result sets.

Comment: @sjagr I also wanted to suggest that, but we don't know if another part of the application relies on the original string format.

Comment: @LarsBeck It probably does, which is why I mentioned that `startTime` would have to be depreciated, not just simply deleted. I'll add some emphasis for future readers

Comment: @sjagr I overlooked the last paragraph, sorry m(